# Execute C++ binary in read/write volume from read-only

Tags: c++, macos

I have a C++ OS X binary that's executing in a read-only volume. The binary copies another binary into a read/write volume, then executes the binary, which curls a file from a URL. My issue seems to be that because the binary in the read-only volume is executing the binary in the read-write volume, the R/W's curl isn't executing properly and failing with an error about the filesystem being read-only. I don't know the technical terminology to describe this, so that's my long-winded explanation.

I'm wondering if it's possible to execute a binary from read-only volume and have it somehow properly execute that R/W binary so curl recognizes it's getting called from a read-write volume and downloads properly. Is that a possibility? While it is possible for me to manually traverse to the R/W volume and execute the file directly, I'm really looking for as much automation as possible.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: download the file to the R/W volume. see the curl manual.

Comment: Is it possible that the default location for the downloaded file is the current working directory?  If so, you probably started out on a read-only disk (to run the first program) and were still "looking" at that location when the 2nd program ran.  See the `chdir()` system call.